# Scroll View and memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, scrollview, out-of-memory

I have a memory troubles in my scroll view. I have a list of news, and activity to display full news info. This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    tools:context=".ViewNewsActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIconFull"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/nophotobig_hdpi_two" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_news_title_full"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey_one"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/example_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_news_date_full"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey_one"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/example_date"
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_news_text_full"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/example_title"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey_one"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgrey"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_photo_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgrey" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_write_comennts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
            android:onClick="onWriteCommentClick"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/write_comment"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_comments_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgrey" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_read_comennts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_gray"
            android:onClick="onReadCommentClick"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/all_comments"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is Activity class

```
public class ViewNewsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
News news;
Context ctx;
Button btnReadComment;
int commentsCount;
double k;
boolean isTablet;
ScrollView scroll;
ImageView ivIcon;
Picasso picasso;
SherlockFragment frag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_CIS_NORMAL);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_news);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type newsType = new TypeToken<News>() {
    }.getType();
    news = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConst.CHOOSEN_NEWS),
            newsType);
    // Set title style------------------------------

    SpannableString title = new SpannableString(news.getName());
    title.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "robotregular"), 0,
            title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ctx = this;
    isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    FragmentHelper fHelper = new FragmentHelper(
            (SherlockFragmentActivity) ctx);
    int w = metrics.widthPixels;
    k = 8 * DeviceDensity.getDensity(ctx);

    // init all components
    commentsCount = news.getCommentsCount();
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_news);
    scroll.clearDisappearingChildren();
    ivIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivIconFull);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title_full);
    TextView tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_news_date_full);
    TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_news_text_full);
    // new FullImageLoader(ivIcon).execute(news.getSmallIcon());
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(ctx);
    picasso = builder.build();
    picasso.load(news.getSmallIcon())
            .placeholder(
                    PlaceHolders.getInstanse().getPlaceHolder(
                            (int) (w - (k * 2)),
                            (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5)))

            .error(PlaceHolders.getInstanse().getPlaceHolder(
                    (int) (w - (k * 2)), (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5)))
            .resize((int) (w - (k * 2)), (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5))
            .into(ivIcon);
    tvTitle.setTypeface(TypefaceCache.get(getAssets(),
            "fonts/robotregular.ttf"));
    tvTitle.setText(news.getName());
    tvDate.setTypeface(TypefaceCache.get(getAssets(),
            "fonts/robotregular.ttf"));
    tvDate.setText(news.getDate() + " / " + news.getCatName());
    tvText.setTypeface(TypefaceCache.get(getAssets(),
            "fonts/robotregular.ttf"));
    tvText.setText((news.getText()).replaceAll("&quot;", "\""));
    if (news.isNewsWithVideo()) {
        LinearLayout videoContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llVideo);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View video = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video, null);
        ImageView videoIcon = (ImageView) video
                .findViewById(R.id.ivVideoContainer);
        ImageButton btnPlay = (ImageButton) video
                .findViewById(R.id.ibPlayVideo);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewNewsActivity.this,
                        YouTubeActivity.class).putExtra(AppConst.VIDEO_ID,
                        news.getVideoId()));
            }
        });
        picasso.load(
                "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + news.getVideoId() + "/0.jpg")
                .placeholder(
                        PlaceHolders.getInstanse().getPlaceHolder(
                                (int) (w - (k * 2)),
                                (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5)))
                .error(PlaceHolders.getInstanse().getPlaceHolder(
                        (int) (w - (k * 2)), (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5)))
                .resize((int) (w - (k * 2)), (int) ((w - (k * 2)) / 1.5))
                .into(videoIcon);
        videoContainer.addView(video);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------

    if (news.isNewsWithPhoto()) {



        if (news.getPhotoUrls().size() > 4) {

            frag = new NewsPhotoFragment();

        } else {
            if ((isTablet || Math.round(DeviceDensity.getInches(ctx)) >= 5)
                    && news.getPhotoUrls().size() > 1) {
                frag = new NewsAlbumListBigFragment();
            } else {
                frag = new NewsAlbumListFragment();
            }
        }
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArrayList(AppConst.PHOTO_ALBUM,
                (ArrayList<String>) news.getPhotoUrls());
        fHelper.addFragmentWhithBundle(R.id.fragment_photo_container, frag,
                b);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    btnReadComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_read_comennts);
    if (news.isNewsCommented()) {
        if (commentsCount >= 5) {
            btnReadComment.setText(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.all_comments)
                    + " (" + news.getCommentsCount() + ")");
        } else {
            btnReadComment.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
        }

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        CommentsFragment cFrag = new CommentsFragment();
        b.putString(AppConst.API_COMMENTS_PAGE_ID,
                Long.toString(news.getId()));
        fHelper.addFragmentWhithBundle(R.id.fragment_comments_container,
                cFrag, b);
    } else {
        Button btnWriteComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_write_comennts);

        btnWriteComment.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
        btnReadComment.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    scroll.removeAllViews();
    news = null;
    picasso.shutdown();
    picasso = null;
    ctx = null;
    frag = null;
    System.gc();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.add(0, AppConst.SHARE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Поделиться")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_share_x)

            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    if (news.isNewsCommented() && commentsCount >= 5) {
        menu.add(0, AppConst.COMMENTS_ID, Menu.NONE, "Коментарии")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.chat_x)

                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
    return true;
}

// press action bar menu items
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == AppConst.SHARE_ID) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                news.getName() + " " + news.getNewsUrl());

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                getString(R.string.shareNews)));
    } else if (item.getItemId() == AppConst.COMMENTS_ID) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ViewNewsActivity.this,
                AllCommentsActivity.class).putExtra(AppConst.NEWS_ID,
                news.getId()).putExtra(AppConst.CHOOSEN_NEWS,
                news.getName()));
    }
    return true;
}

public void onWriteCommentClick(View v) {
    // write comments activity
    startActivity(new Intent(ViewNewsActivity.this,
            WriteCommentActivity.class).putExtra(AppConst.NEWS_ID,
            news.getId()).putExtra(AppConst.CALLED_FROM,
            AppConst.COMMENTS_FROM_VIEW_NEWS));
}

public void onReadCommentClick(View v) {
    // read all comments activity
    startActivity(new Intent(ViewNewsActivity.this,
            AllCommentsActivity.class).putExtra(AppConst.NEWS_ID,
            news.getId()).putExtra(AppConst.CHOOSEN_NEWS, news.getName()));
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Subscribe
public void onShouldUpdateCommentsCount(OnShouldUpdateCommentsInNews event) {
    commentsCount++;
    if (commentsCount >= 5) {
        btnReadComment.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        btnReadComment.setText(getResources().getString(
                R.string.all_comments)
                + " (" + commentsCount + ")");
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
}
```

I try to clear everything, but my memory is grow up like a hell!!! And after I finish this activity memory doesn't clear, and soon I have out of memory exception!

I really don't know what i have to do! Maybe I should use something else instead of scroll view?

Comment: I would look at a heap dump with MAT as Egor suggested. It doesn't seem like you're using Picasso in the conventional way, it may have something to do with it. Try Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView); you can chain your .resize(), etc. in their. No need to hold on to a reference for it.

Comment: One thing you can try is making ctx = this.getApplicationContext() and see if that fixes it. Memory leaks are caused by passing the Activity context out of the activity to something that holds on to it longer than the life of the Activity generally

Comment: I use Picasso in this way, no help, i cant call picasso.shutdown() ( this method calls memoryCache.clear() )with singleton,so i decide to do something like this. I use Picasso in all my adapters and i download a huge number of images in grid view and list view, and i dont have any problems, this why i think the problem is in scrollview. But i will try MAT maybe it will helps...

Comment: O sure! i will try too, I have a question in my fragments i use context from onAttach(Activity a){ctx = activity}, am i use it in a right way?

Comment: If the Fragment somehow lives longer than the Activity it can definitely cause the whole Activity to leak. One of the main problems is anonymous or inner classes, that can live longer than the enclosing class. If you have any of those in the Fragment, look there.

Comment: No, i dont use any inner classes inside those fragments. How i can get context in fragment in other way? or how i can be sure that fragment is die?

Comment: You can always call getActivity(). Try to use getActivity().getApplicationContext() and don't hold onto reference to it. It might help debugging but doesn't address root cause, the fragment should die when activity dies. You'll have to do some digging with MAT, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) an extremely helpful article that describes MAT - a tool that can help you find memory leaks in your application.

> The Dalvik runtime may be garbage-collected, but that doesn't mean you can ignore memory management. You should be especially mindful of memory usage on mobile devices, where memory is more constrained. In this article, we're going to take a look at some of the memory profiling tools in the Android SDK that can help you trim your application's memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure your memory leaks are related to the images for the video thumbs your trying to download. You need to implement some kind of lazy image loader. Just google the term and youll find a library or two that do all this for you.

Comment: he has a lazy image loader, Picasso